# How to draw intersecting circles that are white and have colored numbers in them using TikZ?

Tags: circles

I'm new to latex and I'm trying to get this:
[image]

After some googling I managed to get this:

[image]

using this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\title{FUN A3}
\author{12356}
\date{December 2017}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \tikzset{venn circle/.style={draw,circle,minimum 
 width=5.5cm,fill=#1,opacity=0.4}}

\node [venn circle = red] (A) at (0,0) {$0$};
\node [venn circle = blue] (B) at (60:4cm) {$1$};
\node [venn circle = green] (C) at (0:4cm) {$1$};
\node[left] at (barycentric cs:A=1/2,B=1/2 ) {$1$}; 
\node[below] at (barycentric cs:A=1/2,C=1/2 ) {$1$};   
\node[right] at (barycentric cs:B=1/2,C=1/2 ) {$0$};   
\node[below] at (barycentric cs:A=1/3,B=1/3,C=1/3 ){$0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If I write white for the coloring instead of blue or red they get transparent and I don't see any circles anymore and it would be great if someone can tell me how to make these yellow and light green colors behind my numbers in the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for fun ...

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
\pgfforeach \iA/\iB in{90/3,210/2,330/1}{%
    \pscircle(1.2;\iA){2}%
    \rput(2;\iA){\colorbox{green!50}{$S_\iB$}}%
    \rput(!1.5 \iA\space 180 add PtoC){\colorbox{yellow}{$S_\iB$}}%
}
\rput(0,0){\colorbox{yellow}{$S_4$}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hahaha no it's actually for a course called "Fundamentals of informatics" but we call it fun

Comment: When i repleaced \documentclass{article} with \documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm]{standalone}. It won't compile, i tried merging them like this: 
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm]{standalone,article} it won't compile as well. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: then you need `\usepackage{pstricks}`. This is done by `standalone`. And if you run `pdflatex` you need `pdflatex --shell-escape <file>`. However, the easiest way is to use `xelatex`

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\title{FUN A3}
\author{12356}
\date{December 2017}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \tikzset{venn circle/.style={draw,circle,minimum 
 width=5.5cm}}

\node [venn circle, label={[fill=yellow]center:0}] (A) at (0,0) {};
\node [venn circle, label={[fill=yellow]center:1}] (B) at (60:4cm) {};
\node [venn circle, label={[fill=yellow]center:1}] (C) at (0:4cm) {};
\node[fill=yellow] at (barycentric cs:A=1/2,B=1/2 ) {1}; 
\node[fill=yellow] at (barycentric cs:A=1/2,C=1/2 ) {1};   
\node[fill=yellow] at (barycentric cs:B=1/2,C=1/2 ) {0};   
\node[fill=yellow] at (barycentric cs:A=1/3,B=1/3,C=1/3 ){0};
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A PSTricks solution for emergency purpose.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \pscircle(1.2;90){2}
    \pscircle(1.2;210){2}
    \pscircle(1.2;330){2}
    \psset{linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid}
    \psset{fillcolor=yellow}
    \rput(0,0){\psframebox{$S_4$}}
    \rput(1.5;150){\psframebox{$S_1$}}
    \rput(1.5;270){\psframebox{$S_3$}}
    \rput(1.5;30){\psframebox{$S_2$}}
    \psset{fillcolor=green!50}
    \rput(2;90){\psframebox{$S_3$}}
    \rput(2;210){\psframebox{$S_2$}}
    \rput(2;330){\psframebox{$S_1$}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]